# Trying to use pi in terminal with python

Tags: python, xml, svg, terminal, syntax-error

I am trying to use pi in python directly from the terminal.

I have a generate polygon file that generated me a polygon, then I have another program giving to me that lets me scale and rotate.

```
python rotate_scale_translate.py [-a angle] [-f factor] [-n count] [-x delta_x] [-y delta_y] [file(s)]
```

You use this like this for example. If you want to just scale by a factor of 0.1

```
python rotate_scale_translate.py -f 0.1 hexagon.txt
```

Now the assignment is asking to use angle ***2*pi/12***, but every time I try to use pi it tells me its an illegal value option. I have tried importing math first. Using `math.pi` and 3.14. All these options return illegal option value.

edit:

When I try to use

```
python rotate_scale_translate.py -a 2*pi\12 hexagon.txt
```

I get the error

> Illegal option value: -a 2*math.pi/12

Comment: Where is your attempt that imports math first? What line returns illegal option value? I.e. you'd need to add some code and show us at what point in it you're stuck.

Comment: Ok I tried to add at what point I was stuck. Does that help?

Comment: So you want to do something like `python rotate_scale_translate.py -a 2*pi/12`?

Well, you can output it like this, but it's a very weird way to do it: `python rotate_scale_translate.py -a \`python -c "from math import pi; print(2*pi/12)"\``. 

It would be better to eg. handle the replacement of string `"pi"` for `math.pi` in your rotate_scale_translate.py script.

Comment: This might be a legitimate use for `eval`, but you want to be very careful with it.

Comment: Does the program accept the angle in radians or degrees? It is possible we are just overthinking it and they want you to calculate the value and input it numerically